# After a html page has loaded and datalayer.push scripts have run how can I scrape data that is present in the datalayer using javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio, google-datalayer

I have been learning web scraping in a node.js environment using request and cheerio libraries to select various elements from the loaded page.

I have noticed on many pages in the page source code that a lot of the data is pushed into a datalayer using datalayer.push scripts.  Presumably for use with Google Tag Manager/Google Analytics .

If I load a page in Chrome and open Developer Tools / select Console  I can type datalayer and see the structured data present.

See screenshot below.

**Question**
If I am only interested in the datalayer for web scraping purposes...

Is it possible to access the various data elements held in the 'datalayer' for that page in javascript?

Thanks

[Developer Tools Console Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqRuj.jpg)

Comment: With puppeteer you can get those. With cheerio you would need get it with regex.

Comment: Thanks pguardiaro for the reply. So say I want to still use cheerio  how do I actually reference the objects in the array that i can see in Chrome Dev Tools using Regex. Currently I use var $ = cheerio.load(result.body);  and then use Jquery selectors to select what I want from the html.  But its how to reference the 'datalayer' objects Im finding difficult.    For example from my example screenshot how  would I reference the location-name of "B1" inside the 1st object . Thank you

Comment: No, cheerio won't help because it's in a script. You need to use regex to get the json.

Comment: Ok. So I have to use regex to strip the json out of the datalayer.push scripts?

Comment: Yes, that stuff is usually in the main response.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Much appreciated.